# Freebase query - exclusion of certain values

Tags: freebase

I want to retrieve name of all movies and their genre. It's ok if information about genre is empty, but if genre is known I want to retrieve it.

```
"/film/film/genre": [{"id":null,"optional":"optional"}]
```

But I'm not interested in gay pornography, so I want to exclude all movies with genre "/en/gay_pornography".

```
"/film/film/genre": [{"id|=":["/en/gay_pornography"],"optional":"forbidden"}]
```

The problem is, how to combine it in one query? I.e. how to get all movies, even those with no genre and exclude pr0n?

Edit: it's required to exclude multiple genres, e.g. also /en/pornographic_movie

Comment: This question made me lawl. Exclusion of "certain values".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically there: you just need two "genre" clauses. MQL lets you do this by allowing arbitrary prefixes on any clause:

```
[{
  "id":   null,
  "type": "/film/film",
  "genre": [{
    "id":       null,
    "optional": true
  }],
  "forbid:genre": {
    "id|=": [
      "/en/gay_pornography",
      "/en/pornographic_movie"
    ],
    "optional": "forbidden"
  }
}]​
```

http://tinyurl.com/4449ufg

Comment: Thanks! Now I realized that my previous attempt with 2 clauses didn't work since it wasn't valid JSON. With prefixes it works ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the ["but not"](http://www.freebase.com/docs/mql/ch03.html#butnotoperator) operator:

```
 "genre": [{
    "id":       null,
    "id!=":     "/en/gay_pornography",
    "optional": true
  }]
```

Full example: http://tinyurl.com/3tjdb4j

Edit: This doesn't answer the question. It just prevents that particular id from being listed as a genre of the film but doesn't forbid the film. @phillip-kendal's answer is correct.

Comment: doesn't work:'  "id":   "/en/every_poolboys_dream",
  "type": "/film/film",
  "genre": [{
    "id":       null,
    "id!=":     "/en/gay_pornography",
    "optional": true
  }]'